# How to handle JPA Attribute converters for update query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

So in my application there is an entity

```
@Entity
data class SomeEntity(
    val name: String,

    @Convert(converter =SpecConverter::class)
    val spec: Spec,

    @CreationTimestamp
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,

    @UpdateTimestamp
    val updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = null,

)
```

It works fine while saving as all I need to do is

```
SomeEntityRepository.save (
 SomEntity(
   name="L",
   spec=SpecConverter().convertToEntityAttribute(request.specRequest),
 )
)
```

but how would I manage to run update queries for updating the spec of the entity, I tried doing this but it keeps giving me error

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update some_entity e set e.spec = :spec where name = :name")
    fun updateReferralProgram(name: String, spec: Spec): Unit
```

The error I was getting was

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: some_entity is not mapped [update some_entity e set e.spec = :spec where name = :name ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **HQL** query, you should write your Entity class name instead of Table name in your query like:

```
@Query("update SomeEntity e set e.spec = :spec where name = :name")
```

Comment: please can you add some resources on this for me to look over

Comment: @Lakshya sure, here is a good reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Or use nativeQuery = true with your @Query if you are naming your database TABLE.